# Is there a reduction of security if I XOR Pkcs5S2 and SecureRandom?

Tags: encryption, aes, gcm

I'm using [this codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/14892/1714) sample to encrypt data. I would like to provide hardware protected encryption and a user password as the key.

Is it acceptable to XOR the KDF Pkcs5S2 in Bouncy Castle with a device generated random key?

Is the resulting XOR key more secure than the KDF output?

*note the BouncyCastle PKCS5S2 implementation uses SHA1 as the HMAC calculation function if that matters.

Comment: Note well: *hardware protected encryption* usually means that the key _remains_ in secure hardware (aka usually not your CPU) and any user input normally is directed to this hardware for access authorization.

Comment: @SEJPM Thank you for that terminology & clarification.  Looking into the Apple Secure Enclave, I'm limited to certain functions that doesn't allow access to the raw key material.  Still, I would like to know if I can combine keys, albeit with a different description (assistance appreciated)

Comment: As for the key combination I would suggest making use of the hardware enforced keys. Take any deterministic function whiches key resides in hardware and input the user password / some derived value of that password to that function. Use the result as the encryption key. (Note: I assume here something like AES-ECB, HMAC, ...)